# Xsd2Code and xmldsig

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd2code, xml-dsig

I have a problem with generating code from xsd with Xsd2Code. The xsd looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CountryIdentificationCode-1.0"
           xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:LocationIdentificationCode-1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig.xsd" />

  .......

</xs:schema>
```

The error I fet when I try to serialize the instance of a generated class:

```
"Cannot serialize object of type 'MyXSD.SignatureValueType'. 
 Consider changing type of XmlText member 'MyXSD.SignatureValueType.Value' from System.Byte[] to string or string array."
```

The error happens here:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute(DataType = "base64Binary")]
public byte[] Value
{
    get
    {
        return this.valueField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.valueField = value;
    }
}
```

Event if I change that attribute to:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary")]
```

..i get other error:

```
Type of choice identifier 'ItemsElementName' is inconsistent with type of 'Items'.
Please use array of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyXSD.ItemsChoiceType2, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
```

Did anybody successfully use Xsd2Code with xmldsig? If possible I would rather solve this with Xsd2Code generator and not manually. Is there any other option?

Comment: Dont know if you still care 3 months later, but if you do, can you provide the xsd2code command line you're running?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use only xsd.exe ? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Can you update your question with the part of the failing xsd code ?

Comment: The problematic code is the one generated from xmldsig.xsd. I guess that the problem is with the Initialize fields and/or using List<> insted of arrays in Xsd2Code generator

Comment: You try to generate your class with the basic xsd.exe, then you can compare the output and figure out better what is going wrong as you will have more informations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the DOCTYPE definition at the top of the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE schema
 [
   <!ATTLIST schema 
     xmlns:ds CDATA #FIXED "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <!ENTITY dsig 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'>
   <!ENTITY % p ''>
   <!ENTITY % s ''>
  ]>
```

Comment this out and the code generation will work. This problem was reported to xsd2code in 2009: https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/discussions/45133. It appears that it continues to be an unresolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Xsd2Code options, set option 'CollectionObjectType' as 'Array' instead of 'List'.