# Cannot generate classes from SAML2.0 XSD schemas

Tags: xsd, saml-2.0

I try to generate classes from the following SAML2.0 XSD schemas:

1. http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/v1.2/authorization.xsd - **fail**
2. http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/v1.2/federation.xsd - **fail**
3. http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/privacy/v1.2/privacy.xsd - **success**

I tried to use `xsd.exe` and `xsd2code` tools, but each time I try to generate #1 and #2 I get following errors for the respective schemas:

1. Both tools throw this error: *Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#:EncryptedData' element is not declared.
   Error: Error generating classes for schema '%MYPATH%\authorization'. The element 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#:EncryptedData' is missing.*
2. Two different errors:

   - `xsd.exe`:
     *Error: Error generating classes for schema '%MYPATH%\federation'. The element 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706:ClaimType' is missing.*
   - `xsd2code`: *Error Type 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#:EncryptionMethodType' is not declared.*

To solve problems related to *xmlenc* namespace I saved remote *xenc-schema.xsd* to my local path, but I still get the same error, so it's not timeout problem.

I don't understand what could be the problem with the provided schemas. How to solve all of the mentioned problems?

Comment: Did you get it? I am trying to do the same thing (generate classes from SAML2 schemas) and I am getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with DOCTYPE being declared in the XSD for xmlenc (http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/xenc-schema.xsd). See; You'll need to download and edit the included XSD file(s), or perhaps apply a fix as described in https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/workitem/6972  (`XmlReaderSettings.ProhibitDtd = false`) would work. See here as well: [Xsd2Code and xmldsig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896941/xsd2code-and-xmldsig)

Answer (score 0):

I just had a same error when I tried to validate the XML schema of a SAML response. I managed to solve it by saving all .xsd files locally, then manually removing the DTD and the `import` elements from them, and loading all of them manually.